# Removing Java 7 from Mountain Lion

Tags: java, macos, osx-mountain-lion

Anyone know how to remove Java 7 from Mountain Lion?

Installed it, didn't work properly so installed Java 6 and now everything works fine. Want to now get rid of Java 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done it, I kept searching for mountain lion, searched for remove java 7 from mac and it was the same as doing it on mountain lion anyway:

http://www.java.com/en/download/help/mac_uninstall_java.xml

that solved it.

Answer (score 0):

have you looked at your Java Preferences? /Applications/Utilities I dont think it will allow you to remove Java 7 but it will enable you to decide which version to use by default. Also if you are using an IDE such as Eclipse you are able to set a preference for a particular version on different projects. Can you give more details about it not working properly?

Comment: In Java Preferences I can't remove or enable Java 7. Before I could install Netbeans I needed Java on my machine. I installed Java 7 even though ML has an installation of Java 6 already on the machine (but you need to run it and install it still). It couldn't find Java 7 so couldn't install Netbeans. I tried activating it and it never worked. I installed Java 6 and Netbeans also installed, finally finding Java.

Comment: were you not able point Netbeans at your version of Java 7?

Comment: Nope, wouldn't allow me at all. So now i have Java 7 on this machine and I wish to remove it as Java 6 works perfectly.

Comment: Ok, I understand now. This post might help 
http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-57423014-263/how-to-install-and-uninstall-java-7-for-os-x/ - a bit late - sorry ;)